# This modal logic semantics is not S5, but is it something else well-known?

Tags: lo.logic, modal-logic

The short form of the question is this:

Is there a model of modal propositional calculus that gives the modal operators the meanings

```
◻φ  —  φ is valid, or always true
◊φ = ¬◻¬φ  —  φ is satisfiable, or can be true
```

?

---

The long version, with some background, is that I was trying to put together an informal, short, simplified explanation of modal logic for non-mathematicians. I made a mistake when trying to remember the semantics of S5, where I can essentially drop the relation between possibles worlds. The resulting semantics was not S5, but did seem to be consistent.

My approach and notation might not be standard.

I started with propositional logic with a minimal expressively complete set of operators:

syntax:

```
 = some countable set of letters
p ∈ L  for  p ∈ 
¬χ ∈ L  for  χ ∈ L
(φ → ψ) ∈ L  for  φ ∈ L, ψ ∈ L
```

with other connectives as abbreviations; for example.

```
⊤ ≝ (p → p)
⊥ ≝ ¬⊤
```

semantics (only the 'weak' semantics):

```
⊨φ  if  ‖φ‖(F)=1  for all interpretations F :  → 2

where
‖φ‖ : ( → 2) → 2

‖a‖(F) = F(a)  when a ∈ 
‖¬φ‖(F) = 1 − ‖φ‖(F)
‖(φ → ψ)‖(F) = max { 1 − ‖φ‖(F), ‖ψ‖(F) }
```

Then I added the modal operator to the syntax:

```
◻χ ∈ L  for  χ ∈ L

◊φ ≝ ¬◻¬φ
```

What I then should have done was introduced possible worlds, and the essentially S5 Kripke semantics:

```
possible worlds, W some (countably infinite) set, e.g. ℕ

interpretation now a map also from W : W → ( → 2)

for any interpretation F:
‖φ‖ : (W → ( → 2)) → 2

‖a‖(F)(w) = F(w)(a)
‖¬φ‖(F)(w) = 1 − ‖φ‖(F)(w)
‖(φ → ψ)‖(F)(w) = max { 1 − ‖φ‖(F)(w), ‖ψ‖(F)(w) }
‖◻φ‖(F)(w) = min { ‖φ‖(F)(t) | for all t∈W }

⊨φ  if  ∀F ∀w ∙ ‖φ‖(F)(w) = 1
```

But, I tried to short-cut the introduction of worlds, and did this instead:

```
I left interpretations as in the basic propositional calculus :  → 2

I left these:

    ‖a‖(F) = F(a)
    ‖¬φ‖(F) = 1 − ‖φ‖(F)
    ‖(φ → ψ)‖(F) = max { 1 − ‖φ‖(F), ‖ψ‖(F) }

    ⊨φ  if  ∀F ∙ ‖φ‖(F) = 1

and I added:

    ‖◻φ‖(F) = min { ‖φ‖(G) | for all G }
```

That last step is non-standard, and a deviation from S5.

In both S5 and my 'broken' semantics, we have

```
⊨ ⊤
⊨ ◻⊤

⊭ ⊥
⊭ ◻⊥
⊭ p
```

but only in my 'broken' semantics do we have

```
⊨ ◊p
```

For S5 this would be wrong, as not all possible world/interpretation combinations have that `p` holds somewhere; i.e. there is an interpretation where p is false in all worlds.

But, on the other hand, reading this as "there is a propositional interpretation where p is true" does not seem an unreasonable one for study. It doesn't seem to be obviously trivial, or obviously inconsistent.

I think my semantics is like S5, but with the additional property that the worlds must cover all possible interpretations. More accurately, as that set would not be countable, I think it's enough to cover all possible interpretations with all-but-finitely-many propositions true and also all-but-finitely-many propositions false.

I've searched online, and have looked through some books (including Chellas), but can't find anything like this semantics discussed.

Is this familiar to you?

Many thanks,
Rob.

Comment: It looks to me that you are just using the usual semantics for truth in a particular Kripke model, namely, the model having a world for every interpretation of the propositions (that is, every row of the truth table is a world)  and where every world can access every world. This is a strengthening of S5, as you mention, since $\diamondsuit p$ is true in that world, but not derivable in S5. What is the question exactly?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Thanks. Yes, I alluded to "having a world for every interpretation" in my question. I would like to know whether this semantics has already been the object of study, and perhaps has a name; then I can read more about it. Without a name, such things are very hard to look up. Alternatively, perhaps what I've done is trivial or inconsistent after all, and I've missed something obvious.

Comment: I vote for “trivial”. What you have is simply classical logic with a set of fancy extra names for the constants $\top$ and $\bot$, as all modalized formulas have a fixed truth value under this semantics. Under usual definitions, the induced consequence relation does not even count as a “logic”, as it is not closed under substitution. And as Joel says, it just describes validity in one specific Kripke model.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: just `… extra names for the constants ⊤ and ⊥, as all modalized formulas have a fixed truth value under this semantics`. Ah, yes. Good observation. Thanks.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: do you have a reference for the 'closure under substitution' being a requirement for a 'logic' that you mentioned please? I believe there are epistemic logics that need not be extensional. Are you referring to such extension versus 'intension', or something else? Thanks.

Comment: See e.g. http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequence-algebraic/ .

Comment: I think this may be related to your question: http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0648 . It is not quite the same because we consider models that do not have all possible interpretations, but there seems to be some similarity on a quick reading of your question.

Comment: There may be a relation to Carnap's state description semantics. This also has the feature that $\vDash\Diamond p$.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal. Thanks. I had trouble searching for a reference, finding a few dead links only. Then I found *your* post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/172331/a-question-on-carnaps-modal-semantics-on-the-basis-of-cochiarellis-primary-sem

Comment: There's some material in the book "Handbook of Philosophical Logic", Vol. II "Extensions of Classical Logic", eds. Dov Gabbay, Franz Guenthner; ISBN-13: 9789027716040; ISBN: 9027716048: http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Extensions_of_Classical_Logic.html?id=3PDWAAAAMAAJ.

Comment: In particular, on pp12—, §II.1.4 "The Model Theoretic Tradition", in Robert Bull and Krister Segerberg §II.1 "Basic Modal Logic", there's an introduction to Rudolf Carnap's _state descriptions_. Thanks to @FrodeBjørdal for leading me to this material.

Comment: Thanks @EmilJeřábek for the link regarding closure and substitutions.